# function not seeing newly added classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a navigation that fades in and out the text color on a mouseover. It does this based on inactive class.

It works perfectly except for the page that is initially active.

When I change pages (via ajax) I add the 'inactive' class to the element that was previously 'active' but my function doesn't notice it as such. I can see in web inspector that the active class is being removed and inactive class added properly. Any suggestions?

```
('header#primary nav a.inactive').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({'color': '#ffffff'}, 'slow');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({'color': '#a2a2a2'}, 'slow');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use jquery `live` function for dynamically added elements.

```
 $('header#primary nav a.inactive').live('mouseenter' ,function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({'color': '#ffffff'}, 'slow');
        }).live('mouseleave',
        function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({'color': '#a2a2a2'}, 'slow');
        });
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: use the [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) functions instead. The jQuery doco gives an explanation of how they work, and the only hiccup you'll have is instead of the shortcut `hover()` method you'll need to do a `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` combination.

Medium answer:

When you assign event handlers (whether hover, click, whatever) directly based on a jQuery selector, like your code:

```
$('header#primary nav a.inactive').hover( /* your code */ );
```

That says "find all of the DOM elements that match the selector *right at this moment* and assign an event handler (hover) to them". It definitely does not look out for when elements might be changed to match the selector in the future, nor does it remove handlers from elements if they are changed such that they no longer match.

Instead you want to use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), which will handle the events for elements that match the selector now *or in the future*.

Long answer: oops, I don't have time to write this, and really you don't need me to explain how [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) when they're covered in the jQuery doco.